# singly-generated monoids in mathematics

Tags: co.combinatorics, ct.category-theory

There are many, many examples in mathematics of operations $s$ satisfying $ss = s$ (i.e., idempotent operations).

Not quite as common, but still numerous, are operations $s$ satisfying $sss = s$, specifically, Galois connections from a poset to itself; see my recent post [Abstract nonsense attribution](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53022/abstract-nonsense-attribution) and the articles referred to in replies to that post.

My (casual) question is, are there examples of important operations satisfying other relations of this kind, such as $sss = ss$?  (This particular relation reminds me of the story of an article by X that ends with three footnotes: "The author thanks Y for translating the preceding article", "The author thanks Y for translating the preceding footnote", and "The author thanks Y for translating the preceding footnote"; infinite regress is avoided because, as X explained, "While I may not be able to translate a sentence I can certainly copy one!" Can anyone provide a web-reference for this? I think it's in Littlewood's Miscellany.)

Comment: Collatz's function (on certain subsets of the integers), almost surely.  (Wish I had a proof.) There are similar examples, although across the entire domain of the function no single such relation holds. Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.02.02

Comment: Not sure if this is what you have in mind, but in dynamics one looks at preperiodic points, which are points satisfying the relation $s^n(t) = s^m(t)$, where $s$ is (say) a rational function, exponentiation is iteration, and $n>m$. So the relation $sss=ss$ isn't satisfied identically, but it defines an interesting locus. PS That's a very amusing story.

Comment: @James: Very interesting question! 1+

Comment: Do you specifically want to exclude involutions (satisfying $sss = s$) and other finite order automorphisms from consideration?

Comment: @Gerhard Paseman: I understood the question as being about situations where two iterates of the whole function $s$ agree.  In the Collatz case, this would mean not only that the iteration, started from any integer, eventually enters a loop, but that there's a uniform bound on how many steps that takes (which is clearly not the case).

Comment: Does running LaTeX count as an important operation?

Comment: @Andreas, yes.  There are a wealth of examples of functions which are monotonic decreasing or constant with respect to some well-ordered ranking on the domain=range of the function.  In some cases, it is useful to restrict the domain to those objects whose
rank is at most some ordinal.  This is why I backpedaled on the Collatz function by parenthetically mentioning restriction.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.02.05

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Think about the sheaves on some site as a full subcategory of presheaves: $Sh(C)\to PSh(C)$. This has a left adjoint, called sheafification. There are various ways to construct the sheafification, but one of them uses something called the plus-construction. For any presheaf $F$ it gives an associated presheaf $F^+$, which is always separated but may not be a sheaf. (Being separated means that there is at most one way to glue local bits of data, as opposed to exactly one way for a sheaf.)

If you do this a second time, to get $F^{++}$, you do get a sheaf, and if you do it a third time it has no further effect. Thus $sss=ss$ if $s$ is this plus-construction.

There is a higher-dimensional version involving Cat-enriched presheaves and stacks, where you have to do the analogous construction three times. This would give an example of $ssss=sss$.

I don't know if this continues in still higher dimensions.

Comment: Very nice. Could you indicate why we have to do the plus construction three times when we work in the Cat-enriched setting?

Comment: It's worth noting that the single-plus construction does _not_ have an adjointness property (there is a different functor that is an adjoint to the inclusion $SepPsh\to Psh$, though).  I'm only posting this comment (for posterity's sake) because I was confused for a while about why one would use it if it doesn't have a universal property, but this post explains why (namely that higher iterates ensure that higher cocycle conditions are met).  +1.

Comment: @Martin: There is an article on the nLab.  Iterating the plus construction gives you a weakly equivalent object that descends effectively on "covers of higher depth".  I tihnk it's on the page about Cech cohomology and also on hypercovers if you want to check it out.

Answer (score 5):

While reading your question I was reminded of [Kuratowski's closure-complement problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_closure-complement_problem).  Here we start with an arbitrary subset $X$ of a topological space, and are allowed to apply the *two* operations of closure and complement.  It turns out that for any $X$, we get at most 14 distinct sets by applying these two operations.  If we let $k$ denote the closure operator and $c$ denote the complement operator, then the following relations imply the result

1. $kk=k$
2. $cc=id$, and
3. $kckckck=kck$.

So, to answer the question, if we set $s=ck$ (take the closure of a set and then take the complement of the result), we get the relation $ssss=ss$.

I'll end by mentioning that there do exist $X$ where all 14 sets are possible.  For example, under the usual topology of the reals,

$(0,1) \cup (1,2) \cup \{3\} \cup ([4,5] \cap \mathbb{Q})$

is one such set.

Comment: You should really delete this answer: it ruins a celebrated general topology exercise! :)

Comment: But the question asks for something like $kckckc = kckc$.

Comment: @Martin: with $s=ck$, by (3) we have $ssss=ss$.  

Comment: Oh yes, sorry for my silly remark ...